# How to Prevent Splitting One Line Expression (C++) to Several Lines by VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, clang-format

When I enter this

```
std::string encode(const std::string& word) const {return "";}
```

and autoformat the code, I get that

```
std::string encode(const std::string& word) const
{
    return "";
}
```

I like it that way for multiline code, but for oneliners I prefer the first option. How to configure VS Code for that?

Comment: Do you use clang-format or another formatter to format the code?

Comment: I believe outside of clang-format, this is controlled by `C_Cpp.vcFormat.wrap.preserveBlocks` setting, but I always just used clang-format to avoid having to deal with VSCode settings as much as possible

Comment: @Jarod42 yes, clang-format

Comment: Providing your .clang-format might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your [`.clang-format`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) file add the following line:

```
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: All
```